# Check if intervals overlap

Tags: combinatorics, mathematical-modeling

I have a set of activities $A$, where each activity $i \in A$ has a starting date $s_i$ and an end date $e_i$ (or equivalently a starting date and a duration $d_i$). Therefore, each activity can be represented as an interval $[s_i, e_i]$. Notice that $s_i$ and $e_i$ (or $d_i$) are known.

I want to check if there are overlapping activities, that is activities that are scheduled to be performed (at least partially) during the same time period(s). For example, considering three activities $i$, $j$ and $k$:

```
[-----](i)
    [-------](j)    
                     [--------](k)
                    s_k      e_k
```

activities $i$ and $j$ are overlapping.

I know that one criteria is the following $(*)$ if:

$$
\max_{i \in A}(e_i) - \min_{j \in A}(s_j) < \sum_{a \in A}d_a$$ then there are some overlapping activities.

But this is not enough, as in the case depicted above; in such a case, I can compare each couple $(i,j)$ with the following criteria $(**)$: if 
$$
e_i > s_j \vee e_j > s_i
$$ 
then the two activities $i$ and $j$ overlap.

My questions are: are the two criteria $(*)$ and $(**)$ sufficient to detect all the possible overlaps? If yes, how can I prove it? Are there other criteria?

Comment: Your criterion (**) will not necessarily yield two overlapping activites. $[0,1]$ and $[2,3]$ fulfill the criterion, but don't overlap.

Comment: May not be the most efficient way, but you could check: For all activities $a=[s_a, e_a]$, does an activity $b=[s_b,e_b]$ start or end within $(s_a, e_a)$.

Comment: If you want log-linear complexity, you could do the following:
Using the tuple of times $(s_1, e_1, s_2, e_2, s_3, e_3, ...)$ sort the corresponding tuple of evens $(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ...)$ using a **stable** sorting algorithm.
Then check every pair of events if they are still from the same event: $(2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, ...)$ is not overlapping, but $(2, 3, ....)$ is.

Comment: @knedlsepp yes, you are right, the condition (**) is not correct. I should use condition (*) also for each couple $(i,j)$, not only over the whole set $A$.